# run javascript from an external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 html pages, one that uses:

```
        $.get('alertjquery.html', null, function(tsv) {
            alert(tsv);
        });
```

To get the data from the other webpage.
The other webpage contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $('#test').text($('section').length);
});

</script>
</head>
    <body>
     <section>
     This should be counted
     </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>

  There are currently <b id='test'></b> alerts


</body>
```

I want to get the data that the javascript creates. Is this possible to do?
If so how would I go about it.
The get works but but gets the static webpage so doesn't run the javascript

Comment: Depends on where you want to execute that script, in your browser, the remote machine, your server? For each case there could be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

However, you can parse this data and count the paragraphs in other way.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this. First load in the second HTML with AJAX, the create a DOM object. then extract the innerHTML of your script tag. You can change document to nameofdomobject in this string. and then evaluate it.

SOrry that i don't provide code, but this should help you

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the script inside `$.get` as such:

```
$.get('alertjquery.html', function(){
    var data = $('#test').text($('section').length);
    console.log(data)
});
```

However, it is better if you use `$.load`;

```
$('.container').load('alertjquery.html', function(){
    var data = $('#test').text($('section').length);
    console.log(data)
})
```

You can simplify this process by creating a function.